# Python: How can I set a variable to a random value from a weightled list?

Tags: python, function, variables, random

I'm pretty new to coding and I haven't been able to find an answer to the question above. Here is what I have:

```py
E0 = 1
rho = 0.8

def sigma():
    numberlist = [0.5, 0.2, 0.14, 0.07]
    sigmanew = randomchoices(numberlist, weights=(5, 15, 30, 50), k=1)
    return sigmanew

def deriv(y, t, sigma, rho)
    E = y
    dEdt = sigma * (1 - rho) * E
    return dEdt

t = np.linspace(0, 250, 61)
y0 = E0

ret = odeint(deriv, y0, t, args=(N, sigma, rho))
E = ret.T
```

I want to set the value of sigma to something new each time I run the code based on these weights, but this doesn't seem to work. I know I can do random.uniform to call within this range, but the fact that the values are weighted is important.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The above code isn't sufficient to answer your question. Please expand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numpy.random.choice` with `p` parameter:

```
def sigma():
    numberlist = [0.5, 0.2, 0.14, 0.07]
    weights = np.array([5, 15, 30, 50])
    weights = weights/weights.sum()
    sigmanew = np.random.choice(numberlist, 1, p=weights)
    return sigmanew[0]
```

You can see that the values are weighted accordingly using `np.unique`:

```
np.unique([sigma() for _ in range(100)], return_counts=True)
```

Output:

```
(array([0.07, 0.14, 0.2 , 0.5 ]), array([48, 28, 17,  7], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: When I use this method, I get errors when I use it in an equation. I casted it from object/function to string and then to float, but I get a ValueError saying that the console can't make this conversion. What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to generate a number let's say from 1 to 10 you can use this code

```
import random
n = random.randint(1,10)
```

The first value of 1 is thr minimum and he second value 10 is thr maximum.